# How to prove on function with recursion?

Tags: induction, recursion

I was working on this question for an exercise to improve my skills in induction and recursion. At least I tried the exercise but I got stuck after the base case part. The exercises is to prove that the following claim holds for all integers n ≥ 1: F(n) ≤ n^2

where:

> $$F(i) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} i & \textrm{if } i \leqslant 2 \\
>        i + \frac{F(i − 1) + F(i − 2)}{2} & \textrm{ if } i > 2 \end{array} \right.$$

**I tried to prove it with induction and base case n = 3, but I have no clue how to prove with the n + 1 case, is there something that I am missing?**

Comment: You need a stronger inductive hypothesis. Assume it holds for $n-2$ and $n-1$. Prove it holds for $n$.

Comment: We can't tell you what you're missing when you don't show us your induction step attempt. Simply plugging in the induction hypothesis does the job.

Comment: @QiZhu It doesn't though, if you try to prove $P(n+1)$ using $P(n)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well, it depends on what you mean by $P$. (It could mean that the statement is true for $\leq n$.) But you‘re right that the OP might have had trouble with that, I didn‘t realize it. When you use induction too often, you simply forget to distinguish strong induction from “normal” induction. (And both are equivalent anyhow.)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, all you need to do is to make a stronger inductive hypothesis (in blue below).

The initial conditions $F(1) = 1 \leqslant 1^2$ and $F(2) = 2 \leqslant 2^2$ are clear.

Let $n\geqslant 3$, assume $\color{blue}{\forall 1\leqslant i <n, \, F(i) \leqslant i^2}$.

By induction hypothesis, we get 
$$ F(n) = n + \frac{F(n-1) + F(n-2)}{2} \leqslant n + \frac{(n-1)^2 + (n-2)^2}{2} $$

Expanding the last expression gives $F(n) \leqslant n^2 - 2n + 5$. But since $n\geqslant 3$, $-2n + 5 < 0$, we get $F(n) \leqslant n^2$, which concludes the proof.